# why does $\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac {\sin5\theta}{\theta}$ evaluate to 5

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I got $$\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac {\sin5\theta}{\theta}=5$$ from George Simmons' book calculus with analytical geometry, page 74, number 19 part (a).

Comment: Do you already know that $\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac {\sin\theta}{\theta}=1$?

Comment: $$\frac{\sin 5\theta}{\theta} = \frac{5\sin 5\theta}{5\theta} = 5\cdot\frac{\sin5\theta}{5\theta}$$

Comment: yes, that much I've understood. @Arthur

Comment: thankyou @5xum i get it now so simple!

Comment: It is a very low-quality question. Who answers it, will get his/her account closed for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{\sin 5\theta}{\theta} = \frac{5\sin 5\theta}{5\theta} = 5\cdot\frac{\sin5\theta}{5\theta}$$